# Using execve (linux)

Tags: c, debugging, exec, system-calls

Im confused of the use of the systemcall execve.
The second parameter should be a pointer to the arguments but it doesnt work, it does however execute correctly when I send the whole command(/bin/bash) + arg as a second parameter.

`./test /bin/bash "echo 'this is a test' | wc -c"`

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL); ////works, but I dont understand how since the 2nd param is wrong.
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    execve(argv[1], &argv[2], NULL);  ////doenst work, it should since Im sending the correct aguments.
    printf("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`execve(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

> `argv` is an array of pointers to strings passed to the new program
> as its command-line arguments.  By convention, **the first of these
> strings (i.e., `argv[0]`) should contain the filename associated
> with the file being executed**.  The `argv` array must be terminated
> by a `NULL` pointer.  (Thus, in the new program, `argv[argc]` will be
> `NULL`.)

In other words, the arguments list that you pass in the second parameter *includes* the name of the executable itself (even though that is already specified in the first parameter). This is how executables are able to detect how they're being invoked (e.g. through a symlink) and show the correct name in their "help" output.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[0]` contains the name of the file being executed. Therefore, `execve` also needs the file being executed as first element (index 0).

Answer (score 1):

In execve man we can see that its prototype is:

```
 int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

According to execve man (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

> argv is an array of pointers to strings passed to the new program
> as its command-line arguments.  By convention, the first of these
> strings (i.e., argv[0]) **should contain the filename associated
> with the file being executed**.  The argv array must be terminated
> by a **NULL pointer**.  (Thus, in the new program, argv[argc] will be
> NULL.)

In respect to these rules you're code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{

    char *filepath = "/bin/echo";
    char *argv[] = { filepath, "Hello World", NULL };

    execve (filepath, argv, NULL);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`execve` call executes a program from the caller. Just as any program in C, it requires `argv[0]` to be set to the name of the executable being executed. This is generally done automatically when executing from command line, but since you're using `execve` you have to do it yourself.
If `argv_1[1] = <executable path for program_2>`, when you call program_2 from program_1 with `execve(argv_1[1], &argv_1[1], NULL)`, program_2 recieves an argv array such that `argv_2[0] = argv_1[1], argv_2[1] = argv_1[2]`, and so on.
Notice how your second main does not follow this rule.